# How can I block an entity with user account?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to block an entity like user or bot with a user account. I cannot find any method for that. Also, it's good to exist some method for unblock entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use what is known as [raw API](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/full-api.html). [Searching for "block"](https://tl.telethon.dev/?q=block&redirect=no) takes us to [`BlockRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/block.html) which comes with an example:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.contacts.BlockRequest(
        id='username'
    ))
    print(result)
```